# Is anything known about the enumeration of degree d, genus g curves in CP^2 where g >1 ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, enumerative-geometry, tropical-geometry

I wanted to know if there is something analogous to Kontsevich's recursion formula for 
enumeration of genus zero curves in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$, for higher genus curves. 
There is a 
similar formula for genus one curves. See the book "Mirror Symmetry and Algebraic Geometry"
by Katz, Page 211.

Any partial results known for g>1? That is, maybe its not known for all d, but for some small values of d?

Answer (score 9):

The formula is due to Caporaso and Harris, Counting plane curves of any genus, Invent. Math. 131 (1998), no. 2, 345-392, http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9608025

Answer (score 5):

There is a combinatorial formula for the number of geometric genus $g$ curves of degree $d$ (possibly reducible) passing through $3d-1+g$ generic points of $\mathbb{P}^2$ (or a more general toric surface) derived by tropical techniques, see

Grigory Mikhalkin, *Enumerative tropical algebraic geometry in $\mathbb{R}^2,$*
J. Amer. Math. Soc. 18 (2005), no. 2, 313–377 [MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2137980)